# SPContext.Current.ListItem randomly returns null (custom form)

Tags: splistitem

I have noticed this once pushing the current code to production. following is the code under ddlEnWipeReason_SelectedIndexChanged (inside the update panel):

```
using (SPSite curSite = new SPSite(csURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb curWeb = curSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList curList = curWeb.Lists["Inventory"];
                        *SPListItem cItem = SPContext.Current.ListItem;*
                        if (checkDate(this.dtcEnWipeDate.SelectedDate.ToString()))
                        {
                            // removed the duplicate requirement 
                            if (cItem != null)
                            {
                                this.tbEnWipeHistory.Text = string.Format(" {0} -> {1} \n {2}", (this.dtcEnWipeDate.IsDateEmpty) ? DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yy") : this.dtcEnWipeDate.SelectedDate.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yy"), this.ddlEnWipeReason.SelectedValue.ToString(), ((cItem["EnWipeHistory"] != null) ? cItem["EnWipeHistory"].ToString() : string.Empty));
                            }
                            // Catch the production issue as far as SPContext.Current.ListItem
                            else if (cItem == null)
                            {
                                this.tbEnWipeHistory.Text = string.Format(" {0} -> {1} \n {2}", (this.dtcEnWipeDate.IsDateEmpty) ? DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yy") : this.dtcEnWipeDate.SelectedDate.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yy"), this.ddlEnWipeReason.SelectedValue.ToString(), string.Empty);
                            }



                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you Check out your item (in my case it was page) and deploy the solution this happens.
Solution is to checkin the page and everything will start working fine